# Typescript optional parameter breaks query

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function with a optional parameter, however:

```
async find(query: string, parameters?: string): Promise<T[]> {
    const stmt: sqlite3.Statement = await this.db.prepare(query)
    const info: T[] = stmt.all(parameters)
    this.db.close()

    return info
}
```

If I provide no parameters, I still get the error: `RangeError: Too many parameter values were provided`, how can I make parameters actually nothing if none is provided?

Comment: Can you add the line with the error?

Comment: It shows the error on the line where I define `info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using the [`sqlite3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) npm package. I've never used this library before, but from their [API documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#statementallparam--callback) it appears that you'll want to pass in an object or array as parameters rather than a simple string as a parameter (which would be `undefined` if you called `find` with only one argument).

```
// Key-value pairs as parameters
async find(query: string, parameters: Record<string, any> = {}): Promise<T[]> {
    const stmt: sqlite3.Statement = await this.db.prepare(query)
    const info: T[] = stmt.all(parameters)
    this.db.close()

    return info
}

// Array of parameters
async find(query: string, ...parameters: any[]): Promise<T[]> {
    const stmt: sqlite3.Statement = await this.db.prepare(query)
    const info: T[] = stmt.all(parameters)
    this.db.close()

    return info
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not familiar with that syntax so I had no idea I could just put it like that

Comment: @Daniell Not sure which version you're referring to, but just in case you want to look up more info, the `= {}` is a default parameter, and `...parameters` is a "rest" parameter. Both are documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html).